# Cardano (ADA) node configuration issues 'npm run cucumber'

Tags: npm, cardano

Cardano (ADA) node configuration issues `npm run cucumber`

when run `npm run test` get the error.

```
[nix-shell:~/daedalus]$ npm run test
```

> npm ERR! Linux 4.14.12-x86_64-linode92
>   npm ERR! argv "/nix/store/r8vffmcbmdvx5f1z1ncbgcf70jd0r21h-nodejs-6.11.1/bin/node" "/nix/store/r8vffmcbmdvx5f1z1ncbgcf70jd0r21h-nodejs-6.11.1/bin/npm" "run" "cucumber"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.1
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! daedalus@0.8.0 cucumber: `cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 cucumber-js --compiler js:babel-register --format 'progress-bar' --format-options '{"snippetInterface": "synchronous"}' --tags 'not @skip'`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the daedalus@0.8.0 cucumber script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 cucumber-js --compiler js:babel-register --format 'progress-bar' --format-options '{"snippetInterface": "synchronous"}' --tags 'not @skip''.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the daedalus package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 cucumber-js --compiler js:babel-register --format 'progress-bar' --format-options '{"snippetInterface": "synchronous"}' --tags 'not @skip'
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs daedalus
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls daedalus
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /root/daedalus/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.14.12-x86_64-linode92
>   npm ERR! argv "/nix/store/r8vffmcbmdvx5f1z1ncbgcf70jd0r21h-nodejs-6.11.1/bin/node" "/nix/store/r8vffmcbmdvx5f1z1ncbgcf70jd0r21h-nodejs-6.11.1/bin/npm" "run" "test"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.1
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! daedalus@0.8.0 test: `npm run cucumber`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the daedalus@0.8.0 test script 'npm run cucumber'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the daedalus package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     npm run cucumber
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs daedalus
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls daedalus
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR! /root/daedalus/npm-debug.log

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the daedalus package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system